# Placing EditText by code at given coordinates

Tags: android, layout

I have defined an EditText in my xml file by Id of **EText** and my layout has an image background. Now I want to assign my edittext with respect to layout background which I think can only be done by placing them at some coordinates.

**My Layout Background:-**

[image]

I want the EditText to appear just below the star so lets say I have got the coordinates in the fraction of screen pixel content.

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
int height = display.getHeight();
int width= display.getWidth();

// assuming
int xcoordinate = height/2;  
int y coordinate = width/2;
```

Now I want to know (1)How to place the EditText at the given coordinate by using code.
(2) Will using DisplayMetrics always work for diff screen sizes?

Comment: One (kind of weird) thing you can do is put the `EditText` in the layout and then set the margins to what you want.

Comment: yeah and what about the cordinates will the displaymetrics one always work?